# Drupal 7.14, I would like to send an email when a specific page is viewed

Tags: drupal-7

Using Drupal 7.14, and I would like to receive an single email each time a specific page is viewed.

I have attempted this using Rules.  It does send emails, but it sends me an email for all the rules I have set up.  eg: I set up 3 rules to send me an email given content is viewed at 3 separate URL's, but each time any one of the pages is viewed, all 3 rules are triggered and I get 3 emails.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I could, I suppose.  But getting an email is something I reflexively check quite often, and Google analytics seems to have this gap between  ts "real-time" reporting over 30 min ago and tomorrow when I will get everything (and I do *not* consider myself a real GoogAnalytics expert at all).

Comment: There are other analytics solutions or you could implement your own logging.  Aren't you worried about your inbox getting flooded?

Comment: "flooded" - Not at current volumes.  Maybe (hopefully) in the future, but I am micro-managing it for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

The following rule should work

1. Event should be set to 'Content is viewed'
2. Add the following under 'Conditions':

   **Data comparison** --> the data selector should be '**node:nid**' (or you could use the node url or something like that for the node you're interested in) --> Continue --> select '**equals**' for the operator and the actual nid or URl or whatever you have chosen to distinguish your separate nodes for the Data value
3. Keep your email action since that's already working...

Does that fix the issue?  Adding a condition that will distinguish your nodes?

Comment: Thanks, it does!  As sort of an "add-on" question... I could get your solution (node:url equals 'the-page-path') working for URL's for all pages except the homepage, which I had to use (node:nid equals 42).  I much prefer using URL's, and want to use node:url comparison for the home page as well.  All my attempts of comparing to '/', and other paths did not work.Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but try using '<front>' (without the quotes, but with the brackets) as the front page url.  It may or may not work, but drupal does typically use that to represent the front page...

Comment: Well, it was a good idea but it didn't work.. oh well.  Anyway, thanks again for your answer!  Never had a SO question, do I leave feedback or something?

Comment: Well, you can accept the answer that worked for you by clicking the green check mark next to it.  Folks also vote up answers they like by clicking on the green arrows (for example answers to questions that aren't your question :-)).  If I can think of another way to get to that node id (the front page one), I'll post back!